# Substitute a column data of one data frame with a column data in other data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

My data frame df1 is as below

```
    A   B
#1  1   3,4
#2  2   5
#3  3   4,1
#4  4   1,3
#5  5   2
```

i want to replace A and B column numbers with ID's from below data frame DF2

```
    ID   DATA
#1  101  data1
#2  503  data2
#3  890  data3
#4  1164  data4
#5  5367  data5
```

Instead of 1,2,3 ... DF1 should contain data as below ( expected output is just replace the numbers listed in A,B columns with corresponding ID's)

```
     A   B
#1  101 890,1164
#2  503 5367
#3  890 1164,101
#4  1164 101,890
#5  5367  503
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: where does `409,1164` come from?

Comment: A,B column data should be replaced with ID's in DF2. Edited the data, please check @HubertL

Comment: OK I got it. please also replace 809 by 890

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first column it is straight forward:

```
df1$A <- df2[df1$A,"ID"]
```

For the second column you have to use `strsplit` and `paste` because of the multi value column:

```
df1$B <- sapply(df1$B, function(s) 
    paste( 
       df2[strsplit(as.character(s),",")[[1]],"ID"],
       collapse=","))

df1
     A        B
1  101 890,1164
2  503     5367
3  890 1164,101
4 1164  101,890
5 5367      503
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please tell me how can i combine df1 and df2(now df2 has more row count than df1)

Comment: I don't understand your question @user2014, the number of row of df1 and df2 shouldn't have changed during the process

Comment: I got a way to combine df1 and df2. But only first number is printed in column B, rest of the numbers are displayed as NA,NA,NA..... cant think of reason why. Kindly suggest ! @HubertL

Comment: Maybe you can post this as a new question with detailing how to reproduce (also please try to include loadable data in your questions)

Comment: Thank you @HubertL posted a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134160/na-is-displayed-in-data-frame-instead-of-numbers-in-r